# Problema con la visualización de emojis en juego de Wordle en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estoy desarrollando un juego de Wordle en JavaScript, y me he encontrado con un problema relacionado con la visualización de emojis en mi juego. El juego funciona bien en términos de lógica y mecánica, pero cuando intento mostrar emojis en mensajes de victoria o derrota, estos se muestran incorrectamente como caracteres extraños en lugar de los emojis reales.

Estoy utilizando emojis, como "" y "", en mensajes HTML que se muestran al final del juego, como `<h1>¡PERDISTE!</h1>` y `<h1>¡GANASTE!</h1>`.

El juego funciona correctamente, el único problema es la visualización de emojis. Estoy abierta a sugerencias sobre cómo abordar este problema y agradecería cualquier ayuda para resolverlo.

He revisado la fuente que estoy utilizando en mi página web y parece ser compatible con emojis.

No estoy realizando manipulaciones inapropiadas de caracteres especiales en mi código JavaScript o CSS.

¿Qué puedo hacer para solucionar este problema y lograr que los emojis se muestren correctamente en mi juego?

Uso un archivo HTML, CSS y JavaScript para mi juego de Wordle.

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y muestra un [repro]. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: el codigo???, sin codigo no hay respuesta 